# AngularJS - $http.post keeps sending "NULL" values to ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

In simple terms, I'm making a task management tool with CRUD funcionality using AngularJS for the frontend and ASP.NET for the backend.

In the ASP.NET I've created a table called "KBTM_Task" with the following parameters:

```
public class KBTM_Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string KBTM_Task_ID { get; set; } // this is an ID chosen by the user
    public string KBTM_Task_Title { get; set; }
    public string KBTM_Task_Description { get; set; }
}
```

If I had rows to this table, either manually in Visual Studio or with Postman, then I can successfuly display these rows in a table in the frontend app using `$http.get`.

The problem is when adding new rows within the app. I have a "New Task" button which takes the user to a form. What I want is for those values filled by the user to be stored in the database and then displayed in the table with the others.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="Task_Title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Task_Title" ng-model="tasks.title">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <label for="Task_ID">ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Task_ID" ng-model="tasks.id">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <label for="Task_Description">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="Task_Description" ng-model="tasks.description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the Angular code:

```
$scope.add = function (tasks)
{
    if ($scope.tasks.title != null)
    {
        $scope.tasks.push
        ({
            'KBTM_Task_ID': $scope.tasks.id,
            'KBTM_Task_Title': $scope.tasks.title,
            'KBTM_Task_Description': $scope.tasks.description
        });

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        };

        $http.post('http://localhost/api/KBTM_Task', JSON.stringify($scope.tasks), config)
            .then(
                function(response){
                    console.log(response.data)
                }
            );
    }
}
```

**The problem is that this adds a new row but with all the parameters "NULL".** So it successfuly creates a new entry in the database but it doesn't send any of the values that I filled in the form.

You can check my KBTM_TaskController (95% of it was automatically generated by Visual Studio) on this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/HRvgN7Jr

Please help me as I'm completely stuck. If you require more information, don't hesitate to ask. Thank you!

Comment: Don't know Angular, but the HTML spec says that form controls must have a name attribute to be considered successful controls, and only successful controls get included in a normal form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you want to post data inside body. *FYI: Posting data via URL has limitation*.

If so, you do not need `JSON.stringify` and `config`. `$scope.tasks` is enough.

**Please ensure post data is a single record instead of array.**

```
var data = {
  'KBTM_Task_ID': 'one',
  'KBTM_Task_Title': 'two', 
  'KBTM_Task_Description': 'three' 
}; 

$http.post('http://localhost/api/KBTM_Task', data)
  .then(function(response){ console.log(response.data)} );
```

However, Post action method's parameter binding should be **[FromBody]** which forces Web API to read a complex type from the request body.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostKBTM_Task([FromBody] KBTM_Task kBTM_Task)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: If I change [FromUri] to [FromBody] it gives me an error: `POST http://localhost/api/KBTM_Task 400 (Bad Request)`. And if I try to POST with Postman I get this error in Visual Studio: `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Value cannot be null.` I get this error on the line `db.KBTM_Tasks.Add(kBTM_Task);` in the POST section of the controller.

Comment: Look like a column is null while inserting a data. If you set a break point inside **PostKBTM_Task** action method, do you see **kBTM_Task** model is populated with data?

Comment: No. I've set two breakpoints, one on the line that gives the error and one before, both inside PostKBTM_Task. And my table stayed the same, no new data.

Comment: Look like you are posting an array. Could you try this `var data = {'KBTM_Task_ID': 'one','KBTM_Task_Title': 'two', 'KBTM_Task_Description': 'three' }; $http.post('http://localhost/api/KBTM_Task', data )
  .then(function(response){ console.log(response.data)} );` ?

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

it should be working with following changes.

1: Send the data as object only

```
$scope.tasks = { 
                 'KBTM_Task_ID': $scope.tasks.id, 
                 'KBTM_Task_Title': $scope.tasks.title, 
                 'KBTM_Task_Description': $scope.tasks.description 
};
```

2: Need not to pass the config as the default content type is application/json in angular.

```
$http.post('localhost/api/KBTM_Task', $scope.tasks) 
.then(function(response)
     { 
        console.log(response.data) 
     });
```

or you can use get the request data as the Request.Form in the web method in the API by using the below approach

```
      var data = $.param($scope.tasks);

      var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }


      $http.post('http://localhost/api/KBTM_Task', data, config)
        .then(
            function(response){
                console.log(response.data)
            }
        );
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed that but unfortunetely it still sends values as "NULL". And I've already read those docs and searched a great deal online. Still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: could you provide the value of JSON.stringify($scope.tasks)

Comment: Sure! I did a `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tasks)` and got this: `[{"KBTM_Task_Title":"TestTitle","KBTM_Task_ID":"TestID","KBTM_Task_Description":"TestDescription"}]`. So it is saving correctly, right? It's just not posting correctly. Weird.

Comment: @T.Ferreira : i have updated answer with alternate approach. Hope this will help you. Let me know if you still see the issue

Comment: Just a question before I try it. Should I use the `Content-Type` you used here or the `application/json`?

Comment: the one i used here, and check in network tab for the request, your data should be passed in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117003/discussion-between-deep-and-t-ferreira).